# Smart array P410i Maximum hard drive capacity?

Tags: raid, hp, hp-smart-array

I've looked for quite a while and for some reason can not find this info anywhere, the HP quickspec document search (Which they recommend) doesn't bring up anything.

I have a proliant DL380 g6, and want to know what the maximum hard drive size is for the smart array P410i controller. (this would be using SATA drives, of course).

Answer (score 4):

For HP-branded drives: Largest LFF: 8T. Largest SFF: 1TB. Basically the largest offered. Once a controller supports >2TiB (2.2TB) drives (i.e. 4K sector drives) it will support any size (up to 16 exabytes).

See http://h20195.www2.hp.com/v2/gethtml.aspx?docname=c04111725

Relevant notes from that doc:

- HPE Smart Array Firmware version 5.0 or later is required
- To use hard drives exceeding 2.2TB, you must create a boot volume using offline ACU version 8.75 or later. HPE Smart Array controllers do not support boot volumes exceeding 2.2TB.

Comment: Alright, I'll have to check some other forums and see what people have done with third party drives, I hope you can use extended volumes, since I'll gradually add hard drives as I need the space, eventually getting to 8, and then 16.

Answer (score 3):

For information. I have HP DL120 G7, P410.
Few days ago I installed Hitachi (HGST) Ultrastar 7K6000 6TB 7200rpm 128MB HUS726060AL5214 0F22811 3.5" SAS. This for backup, only 1 HDD in volume, RAID0.
Work fine. P410 Firmware Version: 6.64. HDD Firmware Version: C7J0.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a DL380 G6, you either have 8 or 16 2.5" drive bays or 6 3.5" drive bays.

As mentioned earlier, with modern firmware, you can use any disks you want. However, you should be aware that SATA disks on that controller will downshift to 3.0Gbps link speeds, even if they're 6G drives.

Also, SATA 2.5" disks aren't that large in capacity, so you wouldn't be running into issue with that anyway.

Keep in mind that not all SATA drives will work on that controller/backplane/server combination. Don't try to stuff laptop hard disks in the server, or you may have fan/cooling/non-bootable system issues.

Comment: Yeah, I found someone who confirmed large disks work, you can actually get 4tb 2.5" disks out of external hard drive controllers, and generally, for about $25 more than a 2tb internal hard drive.